# Having trouble understanding python output

Tags: python, if-statement

Why does the second print lookup method return a blank and not the link acm.org? The first result makes sense but shouldn't the second result be similar?

```
# Define a procedure, lookup,
# that takes two inputs:

# - an index
# - keyword

# The procedure should return a list
# of the urls associated
# with the keyword. If the keyword
# is not in the index, the procedure
# should return an empty list.


index = [['udacity', ['http://udacity.com', 'http://npr.org']],
         ['computing', ['http://acm.org']]]

def lookup(index,keyword):
    for p in index:
        if p[0] == keyword:
            return p[1]
        return []     



print lookup(index,'udacity')
#>>> ['http://udacity.com','http://npr.org']

print lookup(index,'computing')

Results:

['http://udacity.com', 'http://npr.org']
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation has a typo. You are returning `[]` if the *first* entry doesn't match. It should be:

```
def lookup(index,keyword):
    for p in index:
        if p[0] == keyword:
            return p[1]
    return []
```

Comment: thank you..I am such a noob. Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend use dictionaries for this case.

It will be like that:

```
index = {'udacity': ['http://udacity.com', 'http://npr.org'],
         'computing': ['http://acm.org']}

def lookup(index, keyword):
    return index[keyword] if keyword in index else []
```

This is faster and clearly. And for sure, you have more possibilities for flexible work with dict than with [list of [lists of 'strings' and [list of 'strings']]].